# Not empty file, but "wc -l" outputs 0

Tags: bash, file

I have a non-empty file (even a big one, `400Ko`), that I can read with `less`.

But if I try to output the number of lines with `wc -l /path/to/file` it outputs `0`.

How can it be possible?

Comment: Do you have the right permisions in that file? Try with sudo or with an account with root privileges.

Comment: Is it a binary file?

Comment: @AFR Doing it with sudo does not change anything :(

Comment: @Leon No it is an html document

Comment: Does `cat /path/to/file|wc -l` suffer from the same problem?

Comment: i have tried right now on a terminal and its working for me. Try to show output and pipe the result to wc -l comand

Comment: I guess your file was generated in windows/dos, and it contains Dos newlines, which `wc` cannot detect. Do a transform first.

Comment: `wc` counts linefeeds -maybe it is all one line.

Comment: @Leon Yes, cat /path/to/file|wc -l suffers from the same problem

Comment: And what is the output of `wc` without the `-l` option? What is the output of `wc -L`?

Comment: @Kent, no the file was generated in Debian with phantomJs

Comment: @Simon pls report `file yourFile`

Comment: Any answer here is just going to be speculation without details on what the file maintains.

Comment: @Kent With DOS line endings, the file would appear to have multiple lines; they would just all appear to end with a carriage return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify for yourself that the file contains no newline/linefeed (ASCII 10) characters, which would result in `wc -l` reporting 0 lines.

1. First, count the characters in your file:

   ```
   wc -c /path/to/file
   ```

   You should get a non-zero value.
2. Now, filter out everything that *isn't* a newline:

   ```
   tr -dc '\n' /path/to/file | wc -c
   ```

   You should get back 0.
3. Or, delete the newlines and count the result.

   ```
   tr -d '\n' | wc -c
   ```

   You should get back the same value as in step 1.

Answer (score 3):

wc counts number of '\n' characters in the file. Could it be that your file does not contain one?

Here is the GNU source:
https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Source-of-wc-command.html

look for COUNT(c) macro.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way it's possible.  Make a 400k file with just nulls in it:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=400 of=/tmp/nulls ; ls -log /tmp/nulls
```

Output shows the file exists:

```
400+0 records in
400+0 records out
409600 bytes (410 kB, 400 KiB) copied, 0.00343425 s, 119 MB/s
-rw-rw-r-- 1 409600 Feb 28 11:12 /tmp/nulls
```

Now count the lines:

```
wc -l /tmp/nulls
0 /tmp/nulls
```

Comment: @Kent, Re *"less"*:  `hexdump -C /tmp/nulls | less`.  Re *"html"*: `sensible-browser /tmp/nulls` *clearly* shows it.  No, of course you're right and it's probably Dos newlines, but this answer shows the simplest possible *400K* instance.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if the HTML file is [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)). The newline characters would have been removed during minification of the content.

Try with `file` command,

```
file filename.html

filename.html: HTML document text, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```